# Filter RecyclerView on the basis of ItemViewType

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, tracking

I have a fetched a list of Offers (**OfferBaseModel**). `Offers` can be of two types **Personal** or **Favourite** . Now I want to show these on tab selection

```
open class OfferBaseModel -> Parent Class
data class PersonalOfferModel(val personalOffer: PersonalOffer) : OfferBaseModel()
data class FavoriteOfferModel(val product: Product) : OfferBaseModel()
```

I have to use same `RecyclerView` for both the items. If I click on **PersonOffer Tab**. `RecyclerView` should filter only **PersonalOfferItemViewType** and when I click on **FavouriteOffer Tab** it should show only **FavouriteItemViewType**. And when I cick on the third **tab(All)** . It should show both type of data

> I have to filter the same list as I have to tracked the offer viewed once in any tab.

I don't want to provide new list on tab selection . Only filter on the basis of viewItemType.

**All Offer Tab** || **Favourite Offer Tab** || **Personal Offer Tab**

But **RecyclerView** under it remains same along with `same list` provided to it once. Only filter on selection on above tabs.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    when (getItemViewType(position)) {
        TYPE_PERSONAL_SECTION -> (holder as PersonalOfferViewHolder).bind(position)
        TYPE_FAVOURITE_SECTION -> (holder as FavouriteOfferViewHolder).bind(position)
    }
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return if (sections[position].shopSectionEntity.styling == "SecondarySection") {
        TYPE_PERSONAL_SECTION
    } else {
        TYPE_FAVOURITE_SECTION
    }
}
```

As I have created a `TrackableRecyclerView`. Each item must be `tracked once`. I mean if a `Personal Offer` is viewed in **Personal Offer Tab**. It's `analytics tracking` shouldn't be called again If same product is displayed in **All Section Tab**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very difficult to make inferences from existing codes, but I would like to offer some logic.

```
enum class ViewType {
    PERSONAL, FAVOURITE, BOTH
} // your condition view

var currentViewType = ViewType.BOTH // default view

fun updateViewType(viewType: ViewType) {
    currentViewType = viewType
    notifyDataSetChanged() // or diffUtil
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return when (currentViewType) {
        ViewType.PERSONAL -> if (sections[position] is PersonalOfferModel) {
            TYPE_PERSONAL_SECTION
        } else -1
        ViewType.FAVOURITE -> if (sections[position] is FavoriteOfferModel) {
            TYPE_FAVOURITE_SECTION
        } else -1
        else -> if (sections[position] is PersonalOfferModel) {
            TYPE_PERSONAL_SECTION
        } else if (sections[position] is FavoriteOfferModel) {
            TYPE_FAVOURITE_SECTION
        } else -1
    }
}
```

and your condition buttons

```
firstButton.setOnClickListener {
    adapter.updateViewType(ViewType.PERSONAL)
}

secondButton.setOnClickListener {
    adapter.updateViewType(ViewType.FAVOURITE)
}

thirdButton.setOnClickListener {
    adapter.updateViewType(ViewType.BOTH)
}
```